# How can i close parent window from child window

Tags: javascript

I opening the logout link in new tab from parent window destroying the session and redirecting the child window page to index or login page. But simultaneously i want to close parent window. How should i do it? It should work in all browser.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429018/how-to-close-a-parent-window-by-pressing-a-button-on-child-window-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
window.opener.close();
```

Comment: thanks for replay i used this but its not working..

it works in IE browser but giving warning before closing the parent window. Not working with other browsers like Firefox, google chrome

Answer (score 0):

Use this on child : `opener.close();`

you'll need to make sure that the opener has been defined for browsers that don't have it by default, by placing the following in the parent:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 msgWindow=open('',window,'resizable=no,width=200,height=200');
 msgWindow.location.href ='apage.html';
  if (msgWindow.opener == null) msgWindow.opener = self; </script>
```

Comment: thanks for reply

but i want to open the link in new tab of browser not in new window.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs

Comment: You are free to do changes on the script according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
```